# How to label like this in IEEE conference latex template

Tags: footnotes

[image]

How do i make something like this in IEEE conference templete.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By "IEEE conference templete", do you mean that the first line in your LaTeX file says `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`? Please confirm (or correct).

Comment: @Mico yes, correct

Comment: Does using `\footnote{blah blah}` achieves what you are looking for?

Comment: Give loading the `xurl` package and writing `... the stopwords from ISO\footnote{\url{https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-bn}} to remove the ...` a try.